# como acionar uma função via outra função

Tags: python, tkinter

eu estou fazendo um app com TKinter e preciso acionar uma função utilizando outra:

```
import pynput
import datetime
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
win = Tk()
win.title('autoclass.enter V1')
win.geometry('500x500')

coord1= Entry(win, width=30)
coord1.place(x=178, y=120)
coord2= Entry(win, width=30)
coord2.place(x=178, y=155)
tempo= Entry(win, width=30)
tempo.place(x=178, y=207)
chat1= Entry(win, width=30)
chat1.place(x=178, y=254)
chat2= Entry(win, width=30)
chat2.place(x=178, y=280)
agora= Entry(win, width=30)
agora.place(x=178, y=320)



 def chronus():
    agora = hora.get()
    now = (datetime.datetime.now())
    if agora == now:
    
    else:

def start():
    time.sleep(2)
    b = coord2.get()
    c = coord1.get()
    d = int(c,0)
    e = int(b,0)

    f = tempo.get()
    g = int(f,0)
    h = (g * 60)

    i = chat1.get()
    j = chat2.get()
    k = int(i,0)
    l = int(j,0)


    pyautogui.click(d, e)
    time.sleep(g)
    pyautogui.moveTo(k, l, duration = 1) 
    pyautogui.click(k, l) 
    keyboard = Controller()
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(8)
    keyboard.type(name.get())
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
[...]
```

a função `chronus()` precisa acionar a `start()` quando a hora indicada for a mesma que a hora que o relógio estiver, mas como fazer com que uma acione a outra?

Comment: Dentro do `if` da função `chronus()` você realiza a chamada da função `start()`. Para realizar esta chamada basta digitar `start()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def start():
    print("oi")

def chronus():
    agora = hora.get()
    now = (datetime.datetime.now())
    if agora == now:
        start()
    else:
```

Normalmente assim funciona.

Comment: Agora ta dando erro na função start:     IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: tá usando algum editor de texto? por exemplo sublime text, ele possui uma forma de converter "tabs" em 4 espaços. por padrão python utiliza 4 espaços para delimitação de blocos de código, e não é permitido misturar espaços com tabs (algumas vezes passa, outras vezes o editor de texto converte automáticamente a tab para espaço). Trata-se de um erro de identação, só precisa chegar os espaçamentos corretamente.